# Xcode saying unit tests past notification but OCMock test actually failed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I'm running the test to verify that a method was called on an OCMockObject.  I'm expecting it to fail and in the issue Navigator it is indeed showing it's failing, but the Notification center is popping up (before the all the tests finish running) and saying Tests Succeeded.

I realize it's most likely a threading issue because one of my tests that is run each time reads from a massive JSON file, parses and then runs tests to confirm the parsing.  I'm betting this is slowing the tests down, but I would think the unit test runner would account for this, apparently it's not and probably only considers the OCUnit tests as passing (in reality I'm using a 3rd party fluent assertion library that doesn't use OCUnit methods).

Actual Question:
Is there a way to slow the unit test runner to wait until all methods finished?  I also am not doing any kind of threading inside the tests or in the code that's being tested.

Comment: What specific library are you using? Also, you say you're not doing any kind of threading, are you doing anything else asynchronous - scheduling an asynchronous task in the run loop for example?

Comment: no there is nothing I'm calling that is Asynchronous.